# How to deal with sed in Tcl script with substitution

Tags: sed, tcl

I am writing a Tcl script which inserts some text in a file behind the matched line. The following are the basic codes in the script.

```
set test_lists [list "test_1"\
                 "test_2"\
                 "test_3"\
                 "test_4"\
                 "test_5"
                ]

foreach test $test_lists {
    set content "
    'some_data/$test'
    "
    exec sed -i "/dog/a$content" /Users/l/Documents/Codes/TCL/file.txt
}
```

However, when I run this script, it always shows me this error:

```
dyn-078192:TCL l$ tclsh test.tcl 

sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown command: `''
    while executing
"exec sed -i "/dog/a$content" /Users/l/Documents/Codes/TCL/file.txt"
    ("foreach" body line 5)
    invoked from within
"foreach test $test_lists {
    set content "
    'some_data/$test'
    "
    exec sed -i "/dog/a$content" /Users/l/Documents/Codes/TCL/file.txt
}"
    (file "test.tcl" line 8)
```

Somehow it always tried to evaluate the first word in `$content`as a command.

Any idea what should I do here to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first should decide *exactly* what characters need to be processed by sed. (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445531/how-to-chain-sed-append-commands for why this can matter…) They might possibly be:

```
/dog/a\
'some_data/test_1'
```

which would turn a file like:

```
abc
dog
hij
```

into

```
abc
dog
'some_data/test_1'
hij
```

If that's what you want, you can then proceed to the second stage: getting those characters from Tcl into sed.

```
# NB: *no* newline here!
set content "'some_data/$test'"

# NB: there's a quoted backslashes and two quoted newlines here
exec sed -i "/dog/a\\\n$content\n" /Users/l/Documents/Codes/TCL/file.txt
```

One of the few places where you need to be careful with quoting in Tcl is when you have backslashes and newlines in close proximity.

---

Why not perform the text transformation directly in Tcl itself? This might reverse the order of inserted lines compared to the original code. You can fix that by `lreverse`ing the list at a convenient time, and perhaps you will also want to do further massaging of the text to insert. That's all refinements...

```
set test_lists [list "'some_data/test_1'"\
             "'some_data/test_2'"\
             "'some_data/test_3'"\
             "'some_data/test_4'"\
             "'some_data/test_5'"
            ]

set filename /Users/l/Documents/Codes/TCL/file.txt
set REGEXP "dog"

# Read in the data; this is good even for pretty large files
set f [open $filename]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Search for first matching line by regular expression
set idx [lsearch -regexp $lines $REGEXP]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    # Found something, so do the insert in the list of lines
    set lines [linsert $lines [expr {$idx + 1}] {*}$test_lists]

    # Write back to the file as we've made changes
    set f [open $filename "w"]
    puts -nonewline $f [join $lines "\n"]
    close $f
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer here! I found that the issue with my original code is because there are multiple lines in the $content variable. If I write all the things in one line, it will work. But your solution by using Tcl itself is definitely a much more better solution.

Comment: Can I do this on a larger file?   Some of our results files are 137k lines

Answer (score 0):

(an extended comment, not an answer)

Running this in the shell to clarify your desired output: is this what you want?

```
$ cat file.txt
foo
dog A
dog B
dog C
dog D
dog E
bar

$ for test in test_{1..5}; do content="some_data/$test"; sed -i "/dog/a$content" file.txt; done

$ cat file.txt
foo
dog A
some_data/test_5
some_data/test_4
some_data/test_3
some_data/test_2
some_data/test_1
dog B
some_data/test_5
some_data/test_4
some_data/test_3
some_data/test_2
some_data/test_1
dog C
some_data/test_5
some_data/test_4
some_data/test_3
some_data/test_2
some_data/test_1
dog D
some_data/test_5
some_data/test_4
some_data/test_3
some_data/test_2
some_data/test_1
dog E
some_data/test_5
some_data/test_4
some_data/test_3
some_data/test_2
some_data/test_1
bar
```

Comment: Yes. This is the expected result. But I need to use Tcl, not shell. Because there are also other parts in the script. Thanks anyway.